# force left to right on TextView's declaration in the xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, right-to-left

I have a TextView that might contains both Latin letters and rtl language letters. When showing both on the same text, it doesn't look good.

How can I force the TextView to be ltr even if i have rtl letters ?
I would like to do so in the xml, and not in the code behind.

Setting text :

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.card_view_title_label_picker_empty_tv)).setText("גל is my friend");
```

Here's my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_title_label_picker_empty_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/label_picker_bg"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textDirection="ltr"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Change android:layout_width="wrap_content" to android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: It doesn't effect the textview I'm affraid :(